# Generating values in a collection following a pattern in C#

Tags: c#

I have following list of strings of tags:

```
List<string> Tags = new List<string> { "EmplId", "EmpName", "EmpAddress" };
```

I want to generate tags as following pattern:

```
EmplId1
EmpName1
EmpAddress1
EmplId2
EmpName2
EmpAddress2
EmplId3
EmpName3
EmpAddress3
```

I have written the following code:

```
List<string> Tags = new List<string> { "EmplId", "EmpName", "EmpAddress" };
foreach (var item in Tags)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item+i);
    }
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

But this code generating an output as following:

```
EmplId1
EmplId2
EmplId3
EmpName1
EmpName2
EmpName3
EmpAddress1
EmpAddress2
EmpAddress3
```

How I can get the desired output ?

Answer (score 4):

The inner loop really needs to be the outer loop.  You want to iterate numbers then values

```
for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
{
  foreach (var item in Tags)
  {
     Console.WriteLine(item+i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can generate items with Linq:

```
var items = from i in Enumerable.Range(1, 4)
            from t in Tags
            select t + i;
```

Produces following items:

```
EmplId1
EmpName1
EmpAddress1
EmplId2
EmpName2
EmpAddress2
EmplId3
EmpName3
EmpAddress3
EmplId4
EmpName4
EmpAddress4
```

Without Linq you should do as Jared pointed - swap loops.